# Smoothly animating container's height in crossfade animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a problem getting the desired effect in Angular animation. A typical crossfade, and the opacities do the cross-fade just fine, but the height is not animated.

what am I doing wrong?

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition('* => *', [
        style({ height: '*' }),
        group([
          query(':leave',
            [
              style({ opacity: 1, position: 'absolute', height: '*' }),
              animate('1s', style({ opacity: 0, height: '*' })),
            ],
            { optional: true },
          ),

          query(':enter',
            [
              style({ opacity: 0 }),
              animate('1s', style({ opacity: 1, height: '*' })),
            ],
            { optional: true },
          ),
        ]),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Live demo: https://angular-crossfade.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo + Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crossfade-btw4y4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

IMHO, it's a quite complex animation, I used many tricks that I would not use normally, their might be a much simpler solution to it.

I considered that the height of the items is dynamic which was the biggest challenge but it makes the animation very flexible.

Since we have dynamic values, we will use the AnimationBuilder of Angular.

When using the AnimationBuilder we don't have access to the `:enter` and `:leave` queries so both elements need to be rendered constantly.

Let's start with the easy part, the CSS, which got much simpler:

```css
#holder {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#show {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
#edit {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;

  visibility: hidden; <-- we start with the 'edit' panel hidden
  position: absolute; <-- we start with the 'edit' panel hidden
}
```

The template:

```html
<div #refHolder id="holder">
  <div #refShow id="show">
    <div>show</div>
    <div>show</div>
    <div>show</div>
  </div>
  <div #refEdit id="edit">
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>edit</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="toggleState()">Toggle</button>
```

Here, notice the references to the 3 elements references (#refHolder, #refShow, #refEdit) which we will use to access their properties when building the animation.

Notice also the ids, which are both used for styling and for querying during the animation.

TS:

We need to define a set of properties

```js
state = true;

@ViewChild('refHolder') refHolder: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('refShow') refShow: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('refEdit') refEdit: ElementRef;

private animationFactory: AnimationFactory;
```

Inject the AnimationBuilder service in the constructor:

```js
constructor(
  private animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder,
) { }
```

Let's code the toggle function, which will first flip the state and then build and play the animation.

```js
toggleState() {
  this.state = !this.state;
  this.buildAndPlayAnimation();
}
```

And now, let's do the hard part, build the animation:

```js
private buildAndPlayAnimation() {
  let animationFactory: AnimationFactory;

  animationFactory = this.animationBuilder.build([
    group([
      query(this.state ? '#edit' : '#show', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          opacity: 1,
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          height: Math.max(this.state ? this.refShow.nativeElement.clientHeight : this.refEdit.nativeElement.clientHeight, this.refHolder.nativeElement.clientHeight),
        }),
        animate('.5s', style({ 
          opacity: 0,
          visibility: 'hidden',
        })),
        style({
          top: 'auto',
          bottom: 'auto',
          right: 'auto',
          height: '*',
        })
      ]),
      query(this.state ? '#show' : '#edit', [
        style({
          position: 'static',
          opacity: 0,
          height: this.refHolder.nativeElement.clientHeight,
          visibility: 'visible',
        }),
        animate('.5s', style({
          opacity: 1,
          height: '*',
        })),
      ])
    ])
  ]);

  animationFactory.create(this.refHolder.nativeElement).play();
}
```

Basically, I used ternary operators in order to not have to create the animation twice, because it needs to work in both way. Items are set to invisible and position absolute to not prevent the user from interacting with the visible panel.

Comment: Awesome, big thanks! Having seen how easy Animation API made it to achieve stuff, I wouldn't have thought cross-fade requires a special approach. A lesson learned!